# Photoshop picture black and white with colour (Lights)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, black, white

I came across this picture online and I want to try and create something similar.

[image: Lights]

Can anyone give me some tips on how to recreate this image?

I have tried the following:

Create new layer & saturate.
Use the history brush to restore the lights.

It's not turning out the way I would expect it to, i'm a Photoshop beginner and this to how I would usually create a color splash.

Thanks

Comment: What about the history brush wasn't giving you the results you wanted? Also I recommend you look into [layer masks](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html).

Answer (score 2):

A very easy way to do it in Photoshop is to:

- create a new layer over your image
- fill it with 100% black
- change it's blending mode from **normal** to **saturation** (this will make the entire image b&w)
- start deleting from the black layer (with eraser, pen, whatever you like) the parts that you want to be in color

What the black layer does is act like a black and white filter. It's a really simple technique, see:

[image]

Comment: Instead of actually deleting the pixels from the black layer, I would suggest using a layer mask and painting them away.  I almost _never_ use the eraser.  It is always best to work in a non-destructive manner, whenever possible.  Otherwise, great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another method, other than Alin's, is to use an adjustment layer.

- Click on the " Create new fill or adjustment layer" button at the bottom of the layers panel (1) and select Hue/Saturation.  This will create the new adjustment layer on top of your existing image.
- Slide the saturation slider (2) all the way to the left, to desaturate the image.
- Now that your image is black and white, click on the layer mask (3) and use a black paint brush to draw in the areas that you wish to restore color to.

[image: menu]

Giving you something like this:

[image: final]

Since you are new to Photoshop and might not know about them, Layer Masks are an incredibly valuable method of "erasing" parts of layers without actually removing the pixels.  A layer mask works by showing or hiding parts of an image, based on a grayscale mask (black = hidden) and can be edited in many of the same ways a regular layer can be.  It is **always** a good idea to avoid erasing or deleting anything in Photoshop, if you can.  Do this by using things like Smart Objects and Layer Masks.

Comment: Hei there, thanks for the comment ^^ you're right when you say that it's a better practice to use a layer mask ^^ I wanted him to get fast results since he's new to PS. Great answer !